# Upper Bound of Fisher Equation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Could anyone please give me directions on how to establish a non trivial and as good as possible upper bound ($u(x,t) \le u_0$) of the Fisher equation?
\begin{cases} 
u_t = u_{xx} + u(1-u) \\
u(x,0) = u_0 
\end{cases}
Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the literature?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I am still searching. Everything I found so far are rather complicated for this problem.

Comment: if you want a travelling wave solution and kink being one of them then you can solve the above equation analytically then determine what the limit will be.